# How can I think about a compact set with a smooth edge?

Tags: divergence-theorem

We discuss at the moment about the gaussian Formula (divergence theorem). There we have that the set on which we integrate must be compact and have a smooth edge. I know what compact means, but I can't imagine how a smooth edge looks like. We had the following definition

> Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact subset. We say that A has a smooth edge if for eacht $a\in \partial A$ there exists an open neighbourhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a $C^1$-function $$\psi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ such that
>
> 1. $A\cap U=\{y\in U: \psi(x)\leq 0\}$
> 2. $\nabla \psi(x)\neq 0 \,\,\,\,\,\,\forall x\in U$

But somehow I don't see how we can think about that. So i think that a sphere has always smooth edge. But in the lecture we also computed an integral over a cube with the divergence theorem, therefore I assume that also a cube must have smooth edge right?
So are there other sets such as a thetraeder or a cylinder which have smooth edges?

Could someone explain this to me? Maybe also with some intuition?